# Using strings.xml w/o Android

Tags: java, android, xml, localization

I am planning to separate a variety of functions between a java library project and an android application project.

One thing I liked for Android was how it handled strings: all string values were centralized within strings.xml which provided ease of localization.

I want this to be consistent with my java library (it can also be an android library as well, i'm just not planning to make any application contexts within it), SO...

Is there a way to have that application of strings.xml put on a simple java library?

Comment: Are you trying to read the strings from your application (outside library) or are you just asking if it's also possible to have string resources withing your library?

Comment: I'd prefer as much separation as possible. Personally I would want to have it within the java library.

I'm also contemplating it on really one strings.xml in an android project, but I wouldn't know how to have the simple java library refer to the strings.xml in that android project. It makes unwanted dependencies but follows the 1 string xml philosophy.

Comment: by java you mean it is not necessary an android library?

Comment: It can or cannot be.

Comment: I am certain you can use the strings.xml and other resources in Android libraries, I have done that, but I'm not sure what happens if you import that library on your PC.